# I use filemaker pro.... I am not any sort of programmer

Tags: string, filemaker

I have a text field in FMPro...

Typical data entry:

```
<a href=http://www.example.com/images/224389.jpg target="_blank"> Photo available</a>.
```

I would like to leave only:

```
http://www.example.com/images/123345.jpg
```

Is there a simple script / calculation that will strip off the `<a href="` & `" target="_blank"> Photo available</a>."`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's `href=http://www.example.com/images/224389.jpg` and not `href="http://www.example.com/images/224389.jpg"` (quotes around the attribute value)?

Comment: P.S. Pease choose a topic title that describes the topic of your question, not your personal profile.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your actual input looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/images/224389.jpg" target="_blank"> Photo available</a>
```

i.e. that there are double-quotes surrounding the `href` value, you could do:

```
Let ( [
start = Position ( YourField ; "href=\"" ; 1 ; 1 ) + 6 ;
end = Position ( YourField ; "\"" ; start ; 1 )
] ;
Middle ( YourField ; start ; end - start )
)
```

to extract:

```
http://www.example.com/images/224389.jpg
```

---

Another option you may want to consider is to install the (free) [BaseElements](https://docs.baseelementsplugin.com/) plugin. Then you can do simply:

```
BE_XPath ( YourField ; "/a/@href"  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Let ( [
    _T ="<a href=http://www.example.com/images/224389.jpg target=\"_blank\"> Photo available</a>." ;
    _T = Middle ( _T ; Position ( _T ; "http" ; 1 ; 1 ) ; 10000 )
] ;
Middle ( _T ; 1 ; Position ( _T ; ".jpg" ; 1 ; 1 ) + 3 )
```

)

Replace the text with your field name in this calc. This calc assumes, all the image names are with extension .jpg

Comment: *"This calc assumes, all the image names are with extension .jpg"* There is no need for such assumption. Nor is there a need to nest two Middle() functions. And the assumption that the content is less than 10000 characters (or any other arbitrary limit) is bad practice in my book.